# npm install no genera la carpeta node_modules

Tags: npm, grunt

Tengo una carpeta con un `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "typescryptimplementation",
  "version": "1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~1.0.4",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~4.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-yuidoc": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "~0.2.3",
    "grunt-typescript": "^0.8.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

, cuando corro

```
npm -v
```

> 6.9.0

```
node -v
```

> v12.6.0

```
cd typescryptimplementation
npm install
dir
```

> Gruntfile.js  package.json  package-lock.json  pom.xml    src

### Estructura de mis archivos:

```
typescryptimplementation
├───.grunt
│   └───grunt-contrib-jasmine
│       ├───grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul
│       └───target
│           └───js-test
│               └───main
│                   └───ts
├───node_modules
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───ts
│   └───test
│       └───ts
│           └───lib
└───target ( esta la estoy generando )
    ├───classes
    │   ├───META-INF
    │   │   └───typescript
    │   │       └───typescryptimplementation
    │   └───typescryptimplementation
    ├───grunt
    ├───js
    └───js-test
        ├───main
        │   └───ts
        └───test
            └───ts
```

en ella no se crea la carpeta `node_modules` ¿Qué podría estar pasando?¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Intentos:

tras intentar guardar una dependencia se crea la carpeta, sin embargo no e descargan todas las demás librerías, sinceramente no creo que deba de instalar todas las librerías individualmente para que se descarguen

```
cd typescryptimplementation
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
npm install grunt --save-dev
dir
```

> Gruntfile.js  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  pom.xml  src

```
npm install
```

> npm WARN Invalid version: "1.0"
>
> npm WARN typescryptimplementation No description
>
> npm WARN typescryptimplementation No repository field.
>
> npm WARN typescryptimplementation No README data
>
> npm WARN typescryptimplementation No license field.
>
> audited 6063 packages in 1.827s
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities
>
> Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>
> > > Error: Cannot find module 'grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul'
> > >       Require stack:
> > >       - /home/travis/build/javatlacati/liniobuzz/typescryptimplementation/Gruntfile.js
> > >       - /home/travis/build/javatlacati/liniobuzz/typescryptimplementation/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js
> > >       - /home/travis/build/javatlacati/liniobuzz/typescryptimplementation/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js
> > >       - /home/travis/build/javatlacati/liniobuzz/typescryptimplementation/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt

Comment: puedes agregar la estructura de tus archivos

Comment: @DavidSantos listo

Comment: no tienes ningún archivo package.json

Comment: como generaste el proyecto con npm init???

Comment: así es, lo agrego a la pregunta

Comment: puedes mostrar el package.json por favor

Comment: ya está en la pregunta

Comment: y si ocupas el proyecto es este: https://github.com/javatlacati/liniobuzz/tree/master/typescryptimplementation